# Adding a service charge to an order with Square API

Tags: node.js, json, square

How do you add a service charge to an order using the Square API? Here is the documentation but they don't give an example.
https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/orders-api/create-order

This is what I tried to add to my request but I'm not seeing this charge in my order. My line items and sales tax works but I can't get the service charges added to an order.

```
{
    "idempotencyKey" : "ABC",
    "order" : {
        "locationId" : "123",
        "lineItems" : [
            {
                "name" : "My Item",
                "quantity" : "1",
                "basePriceMoney" : {
                    "amount" : 2499,
                    "currency" : "USD"
                }
            }
        ],
        "taxes" : [
            {
                "uid" : "state-sales-tax",
                "name" : "State Sales Tax",
                "percentage" : "7.30",
                "scope" : "ORDER"
            }
        ],
        "service_charges" : [
            {
                "uid" : "delivery-fee",
                "name" : "Delivery Fee",
                "amount_money" : {
                    "amount" : 700,
                    "currency" : "USD"
                },
                "calculation_phase" : "TOTAL_PHASE"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks correct me, minus the `scope` (there is no `scope` in a service charge). However, even with the scope, I was able to get it to work and I see it in my test order. Do you have an `order_id` I could look up?

Comment: VuKK1dfJmAqIqecmcc2QP6ptZzXZY

Comment: I just commented on a live order id you can check.

Comment: @sjosey Were you able to find any issues?

Comment: There was no `service_charges` passed with this order. Can you share the full request as an example? We did not receive it according to the logs.

Comment: @sjosey I added the full example I'm sending.

Comment: @sjosey Is there a faster to way to test such as an API explorer?

Comment: @sjosey I found the problem! The nodejs library requires fields to be in camel case than must convert them to underscore case. I needed `serviceCharges` and so on for it to work.